# Create blocks of data on the frontpage in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I am newbie to Yii framework. I want to display some of user controller ouput in a box on the frontpage of the site. but I don't know how. would you give me a plan for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:**

in the home page 'view', add this similar code.

```
<div id="box-id">
    <?php 
        if( Yii::app()->user->isGuest() ) {
            // handle guest
        }
        else {
            $this->renderPartial('/user/homebox', array() );
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Its NOT recommended to add logic in views... better to create a function in controller(somewhere) with above code  and call it here.

**way 2 (Ajax):**

in the home page 'view', add similar javascript.

```
$.get('user/homebox', function(data) {
    $('#box-id').html(data);
});
```

and in UserController .. define some action  'homebox'

```
function actionHomebox() {
    if( Yii::app()->user->isGuest() ) {
        // handle guest
    }
    else {
        $this->renderPartial('homebox', array() );
    }
}
```

you have to define a view 'homebox' somewhere in your views  (views/user/) folder.